# Smarty Dynamic Template Include

Tags: php, smarty

Is there a way to dynamically set a file to include? When I try, I get an error message (see below). For example take this template:

**/templates/main.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {include file='$file'}
    </body>
</html>
```

And this PHP Code:

```
<?php
switch($page){
    case "page1":
         $file = "/templates/page1.tpl";
         break;
    case "page2":
         $file = "/templates/page2.tpl";
         break;
    case "page3":
         $file = "/templates/page3.tpl";
         break;
}
$smarty->assign("file", $file);
$smarty->display("/templates/main.tpl");
```

Smarty then throws this error to me:

> Unable to load template file '$file' in '/templates/main.tpl'

Is there a way to dynamically set the template to use at that location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I figured it out!

Smarty doesn't like the quotes around the variable.

So, `{include file='$file'}` becomes `{include file=$file}`